# Can you increase the power of an SQL instance in Azure during a query?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have a query that is taking a lot longer than I expected. It has been running for an hour. If I increase the power of the SQL server by upping the DTUs, will it increase the speed of the query or will it disconnect the database / only take effect on subsequent queries?

Comment: It will increase the Speed, as there will be more DTU's working to provide your result

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a server login then scaling up the database tier will disconnect you and rollback open transactions. This won’t happen with contained database users, and for that reason these logins are recommended with SQL Azure.

The same can happen with server login users during geo-replication failovers.

Please consider examining the query plan of the query. The query may need to be optimized. Indexes may be required. You may find costly spool operators, sort warnings, etc.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is No.

I tried it and several minutes later I got this error in SQL Server Management Studio, when my query terminated with this error:

> Msg 40197, Level 20, State 1, Line 8 The service has encountered an
>   error processing your request. Please try again. Error code 40549. Msg
>   0, Level 20, State 0, Line 7 A severe error occurred on the current
>   command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

The query had been running for over an hour at this point.

Answer (score 0):

> If I increase the power of the SQL server by upping the DTUs, will it increase the speed of the query or will it disconnect the database / only take effect on subsequent queries?

Effect will be visible [only after upgrade process completes and further there is no downtime during this process with some caveats.](https://sqlstudies.com/2017/03/29/increasing-and-decreasing-the-performance-level-of-your-azure-sql-database/).

> Changing the service tier and/or performance level of a database creates a replica of the original database at the new performance level, and then switches connections over to the replica. No data is lost during this process but during the brief moment when we switch over to the replica, connections to the database are disabled so some transactions in flight may be rolled back. This window varies but is on average under 4 seconds, and in more than 99% of cases is less than 30 seconds. If there are large numbers of transactions in flight at the moment connections are disabled, this window may be longer.